# In RhodeCode, is it possible to use markdown-style syntax in code review comments?

Tags: rhodecode

By default, RhodeCode supports RST-style comments. The docs indicate that both markdown and RST are supported in the README file. Is there a configuration option or plugin that allows you to switch to markdown-style formatting in the code review comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.2.X Series default renderer is RST only, in next release 2.3.0 you can set default renderer to be either RST or Markdown.